# List of Keys differs in JSON response from REST API

Tags: python, json, request, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I use `requests` library to fetch JSON response from REST API. My code:

```
import json
import requests


response = requests.get(url, params=payload, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )
data = response.json()
with open(completeName, 'w+') as fd:
    json.dump(data, fd, indent=4)
```

JSON file contents:

```
"records":[
{
    "parent":"",
     "caused_by":"",
    "watch_list":"",
    "u_closure_code":""
}, 
 {
    "parent":"",
    "caused_by":"",
    "watch_list":""
}
]
```

The list of Keys differs in some response. Any clue why?

Comment: This sounds specific to the API you’re calling. What does their documentation say?

Comment: Using ServiceNow REST API https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=kingston&id=c_TableAPI
Nothing specific to response structure here

Comment: It depends upon table definition